# What is the ID and PW to access the express 443 port page?

Tags: express, https, http-status-code-401

I made web.js like this

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
})

const p = 443
app.listen(p, () => {
    console.log('Express now listen ' + p)
})
```

And I tried to see my page with this URL

```
https://localhost/
```

Then browser show me the dialog which require ID and password for access my page..

..So What is correct ID and password?
Is there any default value for access 443 port page?
Because I did not define any ID or password for access

I tried to see my page which made with express
If I set a port 443, page requires the use of the https protocol

So I used https protocol, then page requires the ID and PW
I have no idea about ID and PW because I did not define